# Safe API to transform HTML (Java)

Tags: java, html, scala

I'd like to take a web page and add some tags to its head.  Specifically, a CSS link and a JavaScript link.  I need to do this programatically for a wide variety of web pages.  Now, I could hack this out with a regex or two, but I'd like to use something more robust.

What's a good way to inject or transform HTML? I'm using Scala, but anything Java or JVM will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).
An example for modifying content in html is [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-html)